# how to make top show multiple CPUs (no toggling)

Tags: top

Is there any way to make top show multiple CPUs by default?
I know how to toggle (1) But I'm running it on batch mode and the output is redirected to a file.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the entire manual I found that there is no "switch" to show the multiple CPUs.

BUT when you press "W" the current configurations are saved to ~/.toprc and those will be the default configuration when you run top again.

So I just run top, press "1" and then "W", close top and run it again and it shows multiple CPUs.
After that I managed to get multiple CPUs in "batch" mode.

I hope that it helps someone on the future.

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, no.  Maybe `mpstat` is an alternative you'd be willing to consider?

```
# mpstat -P ALL
Linux 2.6.5-7.252-smp (ora9.xxx.in)   04/07/06
07:44:18     CPU   %user   %nice %system %iowait    %irq   %soft   %idle    intr/s
07:44:18     all    3.01   57.31    0.36    0.13    0.01    0.00   39.19   1063.46
07:44:18       0    5.87   69.47    0.44    0.05    0.01    0.01   24.16    262.11
07:44:18       1    1.79   48.59    0.36    0.23    0.00    0.00   49.02    268.92
07:44:18       2    2.19   42.63    0.28    0.16    0.01    0.00   54.73    260.96
07:44:18       3    2.17   68.56    0.34    0.06    0.03    0.00   28.83    271.47
```

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html

Comment: top + mpstat would be fine, but I just found a way to achieve using top. see my answer.

Comment: External links can disappear or be unavailable, in which case your answer would be little more than a suggestion for someone to investigate, which would be appropriate only as a comment.  For this to be useful to future readers, please include a synopsis of the key points in the link, particularly as they relate to solving the problem in the question.  Thanks.